# Copying Table Values to Grid Format

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've created a Userform where the user will input what size of grid they desire. A table automatically populates to match their input. The format consists of a letter reference for x-axis, and a number for the y-axis (exactly the same excel is setup, i.e. cell 1 is reference A-1).

They will then put in three readings to each row, where upon an average value is populated. I'm trying to create a way to copy these results into an actual grid format.

Have attached two photos to clarify what it currently looks like in table format and the desired grid layout.

I've tried playing around with various loops... one idea I tried to setup was having a variable assigned a 'Count' function. It would then count the number of '1's in column F. Then tried setting up a loop to copy and paste (transposed) into the grid, setting the copy range as (i + Count.Value).

However, I couldn't figure out a formula for the loop to re-start the copy/paste on cells not previously selected. i.e. using the above formula the first Range would be F3:F7, the second F4:F8, when in fact I would need it to be F8:F12.

Code Examples

```
`The loop I setup to take the user input values for the grid size to put it in the table`
For i = 1 To Axial_Data_Points
            For j = 1 To Circum_Data_Points
                If i <= 26 Then
                    Worksheets("Data Entry").Cells(j + 2 + (i - 1) * Circum_Data_Points_Box, 5).Value = Chr(i + 64)
                    Worksheets("Data Entry").Cells(j + 2 + (i - 1) * Circum_Data_Points_Box, 6).Value = j
               ElseIf i <= 52 Then
                    Worksheets("Data Entry").Cells(j + 2 + (i - 1) * Circum_Data_Points_Box, 5).Value = "A" & Chr(i + (64 - 26))
                    Worksheets("Data Entry").Cells(j + 2 + (i - 1) * Circum_Data_Points_Box, 6).Value = j 
    'This then goes on to if i<=78 etc. in a similar format before the loop ends
```

Current CountIf Function

```
CountNumbers = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F:F"), 1)
```

Loop as is above, but doesn't work currently as I need it to as discussed above.

Any help or pointers much appreciated. Thanks

[image: Table Setup]
[image: Grid Layout]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: I can post if you think it was a good idea (I have done in the past), but there is a lot of code which is why I didn't. I'm looking almost for a formula rather than specific code. Hence why I said above about the loop I tried. 

I'll try shorten it down if you think it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a loop I would use a formula (and eventually convert it into values afterwards). This should be faster than looping through all cells.

Imagine the following as worksheet `My List`

[image]

So just enter the following formula into cell C3 (of the sheet respective A1 of the grid) and pull it down and right:

```
=IFNA(INDEX('My List'!$L:$L,MATCH(C$2&"-"&$B3,'My List'!$G:$G,0)),"-")
```

To get the following result:

[image]

Or just write the formula with VBA into the complete grid with just one line:

```
Range("C3:AP32").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX('My List'!$L:$L,MATCH(C$2&""-""&$B3,'My List'!$G:$G,0)),""-"")"
```

Or if you don't want formulas replace them with the values aferwards:

```
Range("C3:AP32").Formula = "=IFNA(INDEX('My List'!$L:$L,MATCH(C$2&""-""&$B3,'My List'!$G:$G,0)),""-"")"
Range("C3:AP32").Value = Range("C3:AP32").Value
```

Comment: Perfect, this helped me with my problem. Thank you!